# Center spinner in viewport on bootstrap overlay

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'm using the bootstrap-vue overlay on a page that has long content scrolled via the browser window.

```
<b-overlay :show="loading">
```

The overlay correctly covers all of the content, even the part below the viewport, but the overlay's built-in spinner is centered on the content rather than the viewport, so the spinner ends up near or below the bottom of the viewport when the content is long enough.

I've tried custom content via a slot, like this...

```
<b-overlay :show="loading">
  <template v-slot:overlay>
    <div style="???" class="text-center">
      <p style="???">Make me a spinner and center me on the viewport</p>
      <b-button
    </div>
  </template>
```

...with dozens of ideas for `style="???"`, including `position:absolute` with different tops, including `top=50vh`, including `!important` strewn around, etc., but the content doesn't budge.

```js
// Note that this snippet doesn't run, because I don't see a way to get
// bootstrap-vue via CDN
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue!',
      messages: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    for (let i=0; i<50; i++)
      this.messages.push(i)
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-overlay :show="true">
  {{ message }}
  <!-- long content below extends the overlay size -->
  <!-- this moves the spinner down and off the viewport -->
  <ul>
    <li v-for="m in messages" :key="m">{{m}}</li>
  </ul>
  </b-overlay>
</div>
```

I think key to solving this is finding the CSS selector that allows me to change the spinner's position to "fixed" as opposed to "absolute" which seems to be what bootstrap generates.

[image]

Comment: Please put a proper code or a fiddle. Then we may help you.

Comment: @Emir - do you know a way to get bootstrap-vue via CDN?  I've added a snippet that demos my problem but won't run without bootstrap-vue

Comment: Unfortunately. So if I understood your question correctly, you want the spinner be centered on the the viewport even while you are scrolling. Something like what here has been done with the whole page: https://jsfiddle.net/7zu9fjot/8/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Emir that might be even better than what I want.  My problem is that long content pushes the spinner off the bottom of the view, so use *has to* scroll to see it.  What I want is the spinner centered on the viewport to begin with (and I don't care so much if the user scrolls it away).  Now I just need a way to get the bootstrap vue embedded spinner to get styled something like what you showed

Comment: Glad it helped a bit.

Comment: Thanks @Emir.  I've learned that there are two parts to the problem: one what style the spinner that's inside the bootstrap overlay needs to be, the other is what css selector lets me apply that style.  Your fiddle made clear the first part: we need `position:fixed`, not `absolute`.  But the selector part is tricky.  Can you add an answer highlighting "fixed"?  I'll also make my question clearer about the css selector, and maybe you can help there, too?

Answer (score 1):

To get spinner on center of screen you need to make it as direct child of body.
If it is nested it will have restrict area inside immediate parents area.
Try to add that separately or once your DOM ready detach overlay and append to body tag.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Adding this line of CSS on the component resolved it for me:

```
<style>
.position-absolute {
  position: fixed !important;
}
</style>
```

Note: make sure to not include the `scoped` keyword in your `<style>` tag, as this will not work for Bootstrap classes.